# SQL divide number back and forth results in rounding error

Tags: sql-server, types, floating-point

I have a number, e.g., `11.61`. I then make the following division: `1 / 11.61`.

```
DECLARE @value1 numeric(28, 20)
       ,@value2 numeric(28, 20)

SET @value1 = 11.61
SET @value2 = 1 / @value1
```

The results look like

```
(No column name)        (No column name)
11.61000000000000000000 0.08613264427217915000
```

I then want to reverse the division: `1 / @value2`

```
SET @value1 =  1 / @value2
```

The result looks like

```
(No column name)        (No column name)
11.61000000000000079000 0.08613264427217915000
```

The original and expected value should be `11.61`. However, as you can see the result is `11.61000000000000079000`. How can this error be avoided?

Comment: COmputers cannot represent every possible real number. Thee are an infinite number of them. So they use the closest one that can be represented. This results in very small discrepancies. Do you care if your weight is 120 lbs and not 120.00000000000000001 lbs?  If you do, then your only choices are: declare it as decimal(28, 2) or round it to 2 decimal places.

Comment: also, see the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987452) question: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 0):

use `CAST`
like `CAST(@value1 as decimal(10,2))` and `CAST(@value2 as decimal(10,2))`
it will show only 2 decimal places.